# Find the largest possible value of $n$: color segments connecting any 4 of $n$ points with 4 colors

Tags: graph-theory, coloring, ramsey-theory

Let $A_1, A_2, \dots, A_n$ be $n$ points on the plane, no three collinear. Each of the segments connecting two points are colored by one of four given colors.

Find the largest natural number $n$ satisfying the following condition: there exists a way to color these segments such that for any four of $n$ points, the segments connecting them (6 segments) are colored by all four colors.

My attempt: I named 4 colors $M_1, M_2, M_3, M_4$, and denote the color of $A_iA_j$ is $M_{ij}$ and consider the number the groups $(A_i, A_j, A_k, A_l, M_{ij}, M_{jk}, M_{kl}, M_{li}, M_{ik}, M_{jl})$. There are $(^n_4)$ ways to choose 4 out of n points, and $4! (^4_1) + 2^2 (^4_2) = 120$ ways to choose the groups of $M_{ij}$ etc, so the number of these groups is $S = 120(^n_4)$ But yet I haven't found the boundary for this number.

Comment: This is a [Ramsey type](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ramsey%27s_theorem) problem. Joining the first and the second colors, and the third and the fourth colors, we can see that if $n\ge R(4,4)=18$ then for any coloring of these segments into four colors there exist 4 points such that the segments connecting them are colored only by two colors. Moreover, if we adapt an inductive [proof of Ramsey Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ramsey%27s_theorem#Proof_of_the_theorem) to our case then we should obtain a bound $n<14$.

Comment: [Turán’s theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tur%C3%A1n%27s_theorem) should yield a bound $n<13$.

Comment: I wrote a program which randomly found a required coloring for $n=6$, but I don’t know if it exists for $n=7$.

Comment: @AlexRavsky I think the answer is pretty small, because we have to demonstrate particularly the coloring for $(^n_2)$ segments. That's almost impossible for students to do that with large $n$ within the exam time.